# Update .NET Core hosting bundle requires IIS restart?

Tags: .net, .net-core, updates

I have a Windows Server 2016 with .NET Core 2.1 hosting bundle installed to host a web application on IIS. 
I want to update the hosting bundle from version 2.1 to 2.2. What I need to understand is if the update requires an IIS restart like the first installation, or is not necessary for updating.

Comment: You should restart your server. When finished installing the .net core, it will automatically prompt to restart the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"it depends"

The 2.2 bundle will install a new version of the AspNetCoreModule (a native IIS module) that is used to launch and communicate with ASP.NET Core Apps.
The protocol used should be backwards compatible, but new features, such as in-proc hosting, will not work.

So to make sure you are running all the latest components and there are no compatibility issues, you should plan for an IIS restart.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, minor version upgrades do not require a restart, BUT require application pool recycles since some updated runtime .dll's become inaccessible.